# How to write/serialize lucene's ByteBuffersDirectory to disk?

Tags: lucene

How one would write a Lucene 8.11 `ByteBuffersDirectory` to disk?
something similar to Lucene 2.9.4 `Directory.copy(directory, FSDirectory.open(indexPath), true)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`copyFrom`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_11_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/Directory.html#copyFrom-org.apache.lucene.store.Directory-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.apache.lucene.store.IOContext-) method to do this.

For example:

You are using a `ByteBuffersDirectory`:

```java
final Directory dir = new ByteBuffersDirectory();
```

Assuming you are not concurrently writing any new data to that `dir`, you can declare a target where you want to write the data - for example, a `FSDirectory` (a file system directory):

```java
Directory to = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(OUT_DIR_PATH));
```

Use whatever string you want for the `OUT_DIR_PATH` location.

Then you can iterate over all the files in the original `dir` object, writing them to this new `to` location:

```java
IOContext ctx = new IOContext();
for (String file : dir.listAll()) {
    System.out.println(file); // just for testing
    to.copyFrom(dir, file, file, ctx);
}
```

This will create the new `OUT_DIR_PATH` dir and populate it with files, such as:

```
_0.cfe
_0.cfs
_0.si
segments_1
```

... or whatever files you happen to have in your `dir`.

***Caveat:***

I have only used this with a default [`IOContext`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_11_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/IOContext.html) object. There are other constructors for the context - not sure what they do. I assume they give you more control over how the write is performed.

Comment: I accepted your answer although I figured it by myself, because you answered before me.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I figured it out by myself and created a straight forward method for it:

```java
    @SneakyThrows
    public static void copyIndex(ByteBuffersDirectory ramDirectory, Path destination) {
        FSDirectory fsDirectory = FSDirectory.open(destination);
        Arrays.stream(ramDirectory.listAll())
                .forEach(fileName -> {
                    try {
                        // IOContext is null because in fact is not used (at least for the moment)
                        fsDirectory.copyFrom(ramDirectory, fileName, fileName, null);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
                });
    }
```